# dax difference between filter vs filter values

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, azure-analysis-services, analysisservices

Can someone explain how the first filter statement is different from second in DAX?

```
    FILTER(Table, Table[Column] = "some text")

    FILTER(VALUES(Table[Column]), (Table[Column] = "some text"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FILTER function is a table function, meaning it will return a table. In the case of your second example, it is likely that you will get a scalar value (a single value) because you are filtering a table (of one column of unique values) by a single value. In the first FILTER instance, however, you will be returning an *entire* table of the first argument, which has only been filtered by the conditional in the second argument. For reference, I have used the sample data built within the Power BI Desktop version to show you the key differences.

**From your first FILTER example**

```
FILTER( financials, financials[Country] = "Germany" )
```

**Output**
[image]

**From your second FILTER example:**

```
FILTER( VALUES( financials[Country] ), financials[Country] = "Germany" )
-- The extra parantheses around the second argument are not necessary...
```

**Output**

[image]

Therefore, the main functional difference is in the output. What are you wanting to return? An entire table or a specific value(s) of a column(s)?

Comment: This isn't correct, In the second example we also get a table (with one value, but still a table). We can observe huge different in results for this two option if we use it as modifier in measures.

Comment: Is it as simple as Selecting single column vs all column from filtered table? To Answer your question, I am trying to return a table.

Comment: @msta42a, you're right. A table and scalar value are not mutually exclusive. That is, you can have a table comprised of a scalar value (a single value). I have updated for clarity.